# Curl with cat in xargs is not working

Tags: curl, parallel-processing, xargs

How to modify:

```
seq 1 10 | xargs -I{} -P2 -- curl -O -s 'https://example.com/dir/{}.ts
```

To this?

```
cat links.txt | xargs -I{} -P10 -- curl -O -s 'https://example.com/dir/{}.ts'
```

I don't need sequence from 1-10, I need to replace seq 1 10 to cat links.txt, because links.txt is contains not numbers it contains

```
aada1
adk29
amn22
```

Answer (score 1):

If items in links.txt are each on its own line then the solution is as you wrote

```
cat links.txt | xargs -I{} -P10 -- curl -O -s 'https://example.com/dir/{}.ts'
```

If items are on a single line separated by spaces then convert spaces to new lines

```
cat links.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I{} -P10 -- curl -O -s 'https://example.com/dir/{}.ts'
```

Using xargs alone to read directly from file and setting a delimiter

```
# populate test.txt with space separated items
echo -n 'ooo234 qqq345 mmm654' > test.txt
xargs --delimiter=' ' --arg-file=test.txt -I '{}' echo "'{}'"
```

Space separated items used one at a time

```
'ooo234'
'qqq345'
'mmm654'
```

If items are new line delimited:

```
xargs --delimiter='\n' --arg-file=test.txt -I '{}' echo "'{}'"
```